# F5 Big IP APM Advanced Customization guidance

Tags: f5, big-ip

I'm a total newbie to F5 big ip and i have the following requirements to be done:

I need to customize F5  APM using Advanced Customization Standard.

I need to implement a custom bootstrap 5 look and fill for English and Hebrew.

I need a way to completely  separate between login form mode to change / reset password form mode.

I need to implement DUO security login option in the login form.

I need to implement password hints in the change password / reset password form mode in a way that it will show the user which part of the password policy is match / not matched yet.

I'll be glad for help / guidelines with that.